# use the camera connected via USB instead of the built-in camera

Tags: android, usb, android-camera

I want to create an application in android which, when connect an USB camera device to the android device, then all applications should detect the external camera as the primary camera. For example if we open camera application then the device take the picture from the one which is connected via USB. Is there a way to do this?

Please do not close this question as not a real question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot do this by writing a simple app as you do not decide which is the default camera. That is done by the system firmware, and you cannot modify this through the Android SDK.

The only way to achieve this would be to customize Android at a source level and add code to automatically switch the default camera to the one connected by USB when it is available.

Comment: i have a tv device that has no camera. is it possible to make usb camera or IP camera as a default android camera

Answer (score 3):

you can use OpenCV,according to [this document](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Android2.3.0#NativecamerasupportinOpenCV) it is quite easy.

to capture frames from default cam:

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( CV_CAP_ANDROID + 0 );
```

to capture frames from usb:

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( CV_CAP_ANDROID + 1 );
```

OpenCV is open source you can get the source code from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/2.4.0/)
, you will need [Android cmake project](http://code.google.com/p/android-cmake/)

**Edit:**

android is a linux based operating system , you can download the [Android terminal emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en) and customize your audio and video settings like in linux , you can either disable the built-in camera in the device manager or change the settings to use the external webcam as default. but i'd disable the built-in camera completely personally.

Comment: The OP doesn't want to use the USB camera himself. He wants to make it the default for every app on the device.

Comment: @Ahmed Kato Is my device needs to be rooted if i want to use Android terminal emulator app ?